# Python function returns "list of lists" instead of flat list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My goal is to pass a pandas dataframe, lower bound value, and upper bound value to a function, interpolate all NaNs within the bounds using nearest neighbor, return the interpolated df and the number of interpolations made. Sometimes there are several NaNs in a row, hence the nested loop to look for the next non-NaN value for interpolation.

```
def gap_clean(df, lb, ub):
    data = {'a':df.index, 'b':df.values}     
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)
    lb_index = df[df['a'] == lb].index.values[0]
    ub_index = df[df['a'] == ub].index.values[0]
    interpolations = 0
    for i in range(lb_index, ub_index+1):
        if np.isnan(df2.loc[i, 'b']):
            for j in range(1, 20):
                if ~np.isnan(df2.loc[i+j, 'b']):
                    interpolations += 1
                    df2.loc[i, 'b'] = (df2.loc[i - 1, 'b'] + df2.loc[i + j, 'b']) / 2
                    break
    df2 = df2.set_index(['a'])
return df2, interpolations;
```

The expected behavior for the returned df is I can call  and get

```
In []: df.values
Out[]: [1.23,
         2.44,
         3.55, 
          ...]
```

Instead I get:

```
In []: df.values
Out[]: array([[1.23],
              [2.44],
              [3.55],
                ...])
```

I am able to work around this and get the expected result if I call:

```
reduce(operator.add, df.values.tolist())
```

to flatten it, but that is a pain to do every single time. How can I modify the function to give the expected behavior?

Comment: You can try ``df['col'].values``

Comment: That is the easiest solution, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your function to return a `DataFrame` there's not much you can do. This is just how Pandas `DataFrame.values` function works.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html

```
>>> pd.DataFrame([1,2,3]).values
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
```

You might want to simply the data from your function already in desired format:

```
return [e[0] for e in df.values], interpolations
```

Note: this method of converting is called **list comprehension**. Seems simpler than your `reduce(operator.add ...)`

Comment: I need the index too. Won't this return just the values?

Comment: yes this option returns only values. If you need a data frame, then I don't understand what you want to change in your function. It returns a dataframe already. And if you look how to convert df to list of values, example is given

Answer (score 0):

You could use the pandas API support for interpolation and won't need the nan checks etc. The `limit_area` option for interpolation further supports the upper and lower bounds.

[Check the interpolation API](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html)

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful, I didn't notice the interpolation API had limit_area and consecutive NaN conditionals.